# How multi-tab logout can be managed in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
window.addEventListener('storage', e => {
  if(e.key === 'access_token' && e.oldValue && !e.newValue) {
    store.dispatch(userSignOut());
  }
})
```

If this is a suitable solution, then where(lifecycle event) should i paste this?

Comment: it is indeed a go-to solution. you can add this in the dashboard component's constructor which you show after user login or root components constructor. you can also remove this event listener when user logs out or that component is unmounted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to do that is by using the [`BrodcastChannel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API) feature in Javascript. The Broadcast Channel API allows simple communication between browsing contexts (that is windows, tabs, frames, or iframes) with the same origin (usually pages from the same site).

For example:

```js
// Connecting to a broadcast channel
const userChannel = new BroadcastChannel('user');

function signOut() {
    // and after that, we have to broadcast a message to the user channel which user has signed out from the application as below:
    userChannel.postMessage({
        userId: "", // If the user opened your app in multi-tabs and signed-in with multi accounts, you need to put the userId here to identify which account has signed out exactly
        payload: {
            type: "SIGN_OUT"
        }
    });
}
}
```

So we created the user's BrodcastChannel but we need to observe on sent messages by user's channel and do the right actions by payload type.

```js
userChannel.onmessage = data => { 
   if(data.payload.type === "SIGN_OUT") {
     // As I talked before about multi-accounts, we need to check the current user id with the sent userId by the userChannel and if they were the same, we have to dispatch the userSignOut action.
     store.dispatch(userSignOut());
   }
}
```

Comment: It is not supported in IE 11 or in safari browser.

Comment: @YashOjha Is there anyway to support that too, Please elaborate that as an answer if possible??

Comment: No, I have no other idea to do that. but it is the best way to do that if you don't want to use a WebSocket or SSE(Serve sent event - HTML5 feature).

Answer (score 1):

[enter link description here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)

Try with focus Listener `isFocused`

Also check

React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to them:

```
willFocus - the screen will focus
didFocus - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition 
completed)
willBlur - the screen will be unfocused
didBlur - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition 
completed)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should create an action, something like `CHECK_CREDENTIALS`, and dispatch it on every API call. This way, if you are removing user credentials from `localStorage`, every tab will be logged out on 1st call.

However, this is something your server should be capable of. When the token is expired/deleted, it is logical that you should get some comprehensive error.